# Local static IP for device based on MAC address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem, static-ip

I have `Genexis Platinum-4410` Wifi modem. What am trying to implement is, I have a device(camera) that automatically connects to this LAN through WiFi. I would like to assign a particular local IP (say, 192.168.1.20) always. But the device doesn't have any provision to assign this IP. So the only way seem to be doing it from the modem/router. I mean my idea is to assign this local IP to this device based on the device's MAC id.

But am unable to figure out whether this is possible in my `Genexis Platinum-4410`. There's no proper documentation available. And my ISP's support guys doesn't know either. I have access to the modem's control panel. So my question is, is it possible to assign static IP using the MAC id of the device, in this particular modem? If so, can you please provide the steps. If it's not possible, what would be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check in the DHCP Settings if there is an IP Reservation option.
Usually under Net > LAN.

I guess that we are talking about a modem-router.

Comment: thank you. Am not able to see any "IP Reservation" option. Please find the screenshot: https://imgur.com/vVdJl2o

Comment: Looks like you have no reservation option, if you have only One device connected you can set up, as a workaround, the same starting and finishing ip address in the pool.
You can Also try to update the firmware, maybe you get additional options.